# Add multiple value in select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array such as  `[1,2,3]`.

I want to show each element of the array in a select option menu.

I am currently using `.append`, but when I do this it is added to the existing items in the select, which i do not want.  I want them to be the only options in the select when this runs.

Here is the jQuery so far:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
$("#sec").append("<option>"+data2[i]+"</option>");
}
```

Comment: `$("#sec").empty().html('<option>' + data2.join('</option><option>') + '</option>');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before appending empty the select tag using [`empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) method.

```
$("#sec").empty();
for (var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
  $("#sec").append("<option>"+data2[i]+"</option>");
}
```

---

Or generate an HTML string and replace the entire content with [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html) method.

```
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
  html += "<option>"+data2[i]+"</option>";
}
$("#sec").html(html);
```

---

Or more simple way using [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method, which helps to avoid the loop.

```
$("#sec").html('<option>' + data2.join('</option><option>') + '</option>');
```